# Derive this variant of Farkas' lemma, through another variant of Farkas' lemma.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, duality-theorems

Derive the following variant of Farkas' lemma:

For each $mxn$ matrix A and vector $b\in\mathbb{R^m}$ one of the following statements is true:

- $\exists x\in\mathbb{R^n}$ such that $Ax=b$
- $\exists y\in\mathbb{R^m}$ such that $y^TA=0$ and $y^Tb=1$

By this version of Farkas' lemma:

For each $mxn$ matrix A and vectors $b\in\mathbb{R^m}$ and $c\in\mathbb{R^n}$ one of the following statements is true:

- $\{x\in\mathbb{R^n}\mid Ax=b,x\geq0\}\neq \emptyset$
- $\{y\in\mathbb{R^m}\mid y^TA\geq0,y^Tb<0\}\neq \emptyset$

I have no idea where to start this. Can someone help me in which direction to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the second variant of Farkas's lemma for matrix $A$ and vector $-b$. So now you also have 
For each $m$x$n$ matrix A and vector $b\in R^m$ one of the following statements is true:

{$x\in R^n | Ax=b,x\le0$}$\ne\varnothing$

{$y\in R^m | y^TA\le0,y^Tb\gt0$}$\ne\varnothing$

Denoting $y^Tb=k, k\ne0$ use Farkas's lemma one more time now for vector $b/k$

Comment: Is it true that you made a mistake and $y^TA\geq0$ should be $y^TA\leq0$? So that you can say $y^TA=0$? which you need to show.

Comment: Yes, as a consequence of copying. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: But the conclusion that this shows that the above $y^T=0$ is correct right?

Comment: Meaning $y^TA=0$ ? $y^T=0$ would imply $y^Tb\ne1$

Comment: Yes!, a mistake aswell

Comment: In that case, yes, $y^TA=0$ :)

Comment: And with the vector $b/k$, you should come to the conclusion $y^Tb=1$?

Comment: Exactly, just scaling the vector by a positive $k$. All inequalities will not change.

Comment: You mean scale the vector by $1/k$? and you're in the new case where $y^TA=0$ and you take $y^Tb=k$. as you scale the vector by $1/ k$ you need to scale the $0$ with $1/k$ which is 0 and scale it with $k$ which gives 1? and then you've shown the derivation?

Comment: $y^TA=0$ doesn't change, the only thing that changes is $y^Tb=k$ which is now $y^Tb'=1$ where $b'=b/k$.

Comment: But $y^TA=0$ doesn't change because $0\cdot 1/k=0$ right? Not because it doesn't contain $b$?

Comment: In this case, because it doesn't contain $b$. Actually you can scale vector $y$ too, then $y^TA=0$ doesn't change because $0*1/k=0$.

Comment: But why does the sign change then with $y^TA\geq0$ when the vector is $-b$ as this doesn't containt $b$?

Comment: Because in order to maintain $y^Tb<0$, $y$ would have to change it's sign.

Comment: ah I see it now, thnx for all the help!