# Farkas' lemma for variables in the natural numbers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, optimization, discrete-optimization

A lot of questions regarding the Farkas' lemma has already been done here. Most of them seems to be related to consequences of the Farkas' lemma, for example, see [[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1496750/derive-this-variant-of-farkas-lemma-through-another-variant-of-farkas-lemma?rq=1), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399994/linear-algebra-classic-farkas-lemma-application?rq=1), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2256726/proving-farkas-lemma-by-using-theorem-of-alternatives?rq=1)]. This means that the problem of deciding whether a linear programming is feasible or not is well established. On the other hand, there is a class of similar problems called [*unbounded knapsack problems*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), but, at least up to my knowledge $-$ which is modest $-$, it does not seem to have a similar characterization for the feasibility as in linear programming. So... since these problems are still quite interesting by themselves, I wonder,

> what is a necessary and sufficient condition for an *unbounded knapsack problem* to be feasible?

Precisely,

> given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and a vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$, there is a result similar to the theorems of the alternative so that it gives a necessary and sufficient condition to the system
> $$\begin{align*}
> A x \leq &\  b \\
> x \geq &\  0 \\
> \end{align*}$$ to have a solution with $x \in \mathbb{Z}^n$?

Comment: Now asked on MathOverflow: [Farkas' lemma for variables in the natural numbers](https://mathoverflow.net/q/435790)

Comment: Thank you, Martin!

Comment: This entails looking into the decomposition of $A$ and $b$ elements onto a Hamel basis of $\mathbb{R}$, doesn't it? It looks very remote from Farkas lemma, which has a geometric nature. We would probably be nearer to Farkas lemma if asking for $Ax \ge b$, instead of $Ax = b$.

Comment: I will make the change then. =) I am not sure about your question, but It probably  does not.

Comment: I actually think this question might be hard even in Ax=b and x≥0 form. This system generalizes the ideas of system of linear Diophantine equations, which is hard even when there is no inequality constraint.

Comment: @R.W.Prado It is actually easier with inequality, it seems to me; this is the reason why I suggested the inequality instead of the equality. At least if looking separately for necessary and sufficient conditions. I now give a try at it.

Comment: @R.W.Prado Note that Lasserre did publish a paper with what he calls a discrete version of Farkas lemma. But it seems very far in spirit from the original Farkas lemma. https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-Discrete-Farkas-Lemma-Lasserre/367c87cd0b2f0e2e8e2f3e0fd895d21d82a2cc21

Comment: It's not far from the spirit. We have to find the coeficients of the polinomial $Q_j$, for $n \geq j \geq 1$, which is possible to do. Not a easy task, but a possible one.

Comment: Note that it does not contradict my answer since the linear program at hand has an exponential number of constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question asks for a certificate for both satisfiability and unsatisfiability. However, since the unbounded knapsack problem is $\mathcal{NP}$-complete, it is unlikely there exists a short certificate for this, otherwise the problem would be in $\mathcal{NP} \cap co\mathcal{NP}$, which is very unlikely.

In fact, if any $\mathcal{NP}$-complete problem belongs to $\mathcal{NP} \cap \text{co}\mathcal{NP}$, then $\mathcal{NP} = \text{co}\mathcal{NP}$, which is equivalent to a collapse to the first level of the polynomial hierarchy. It is a widely believed conjecture that any collapse of the polynomial hierarchy is unlikely, especially to the first level.

It would for example imply that $SAT$ is also in co$\mathcal{NP}$, which means that even if we had to do a long computation to show that no solution exists to a given boolean formulation, we would be able to generate a short proof for it.

In a more general manner, this explains why there is no equivalent of the Farkas Lemma for integer programming, since integer programming is $\mathcal{NP}$-hard